# Is EMC compatibility required for non-consumer devices?

Tags: emc

I'm working for company X on some devices for smart building (lightning, energy management etc).

These devices are owned by a company X and installed in other companies buildings (shops, restaurants etc).

Company X sells "building management services" to company Y. Devices are used "internally" by company X that manufactures them, but in buildings used by many people.

Devices are installed in electrical cabinets (I'm not sure if this is correct name in english) and nobody has access to them except our company X electricans.

We never sell these devices to the "end users", we use them like "industrial equipment".

Questions:

**Do we actually need EMC compliance tests/certification in European Union?**

Comment: I've worked on industrial products most of my career and have always had EMC specs to deal with.

Comment: Yes. Industrial equipment has different requirements with CE. Tougher immunity requirements is one. You might also have to comply with the machinery directive and maybe specific standards for lighting etc. I’d suggest you engage the services of a consultant. It will be cheaper than purchasing all the standards.

Comment: To clarify: Assuming that there are no underlying technical problems with EMI from unwanted radiated emissions or received interference, and assuming the EU laws (EM Compliance) still allow self-certification without requiring outside lab work, you're only asking about company X's **legal and ethical obligations** under the EU's EMC laws, in this situation where the equipment is not shipped but rather 'leased' or used in the course of providing a service, correct?

Comment: Think about why EMC is "a thing" in the first place: If your device goes haywire whenever the equipment in the box next to it starts up (susceptibility), you're going to get a lot more maintenance calls, driving up costs for company X. And if your devices interfere with the operation of other devices used by company Y or their customers (radiation), you'll develop a reputation that will keep other companies from coming to you in the first place. So, regardless of regulatory requirements, you're going to have *internal* practices designed to optimize profits.

Comment: ... And it's simpler for everyone if those internal standards are based on the relevant regulations, since that's what everyone is familiar with and is set up to test for.